# how to get message authentication code for BouncyCastle AES-CCM encrypted message

Tags: macos, aes

I have encrypted some text as follows:

```
Cipher in = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CCM/NoPadding", "BC");
in.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(_nonce));
encoded = in.doFinal(payload);
```

Works great. I want to get the MAC, so I try this:

```
byte[] K = Hex.decode(bek.getBytes());
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(K, "AES");
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("AES/CCM/NoPadding", "BC");
```

but get a "no such algorithm: AES/CCM/NoPadding for provider BC".

So, what algorithm is used to extract the MAC from an AES/CCM encrypted message? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The CCM mode implies the use of the CBC block cipher MAC for AES, so that's the algorithm you should be using, but I haven't written code which uses this myself.  I know that BouncyCastle implements this with the CBCBlockCipherMac class, but I'm not 100% sure of the correct algorithm name, but looking in the sourcecode it appears to be "AESMac" (which uses CBC mode and zero-padding by default).

Answer (score 1):

yes there is authentication tag(mac) exist in cypher text. if have used n bit of mac in processing then the last n-bit in your cypher text is mac.

you can find this by code also

```
 CCMBlockCipher cipher = new CCMBlockCipher(engine);
    cipher.init(true, params);
    byte[] outputText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(inputData.length)];
    int outputLen = cipher.processBytes(inputData, 0, inputData.length,
            inputData, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(outputText, outputLen);
//this is your mac
cipher.getMac();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the JCE to extract the MAC, it is simply not supported. You will have to use the Bouncycastle crypto API directly. The class [CCMBlockCipher](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/CCMBlockCipher.html) has a `getMac` method to retrieve the Mac bytes.